# The jump address calculation

Tags: assembly, mips, mips32

Suppose that I want to jump from 0x20000000 to 0x1FFFFFFC. For this, I should write the jump instruction on this address.

I got jump instruction machine code: 0000 1011 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 with leftmost 6bit opcode and 26bit relative address. So, to check if I really jumped to the desired address, I do everything backward: take off the first 6 bits of opcode and get 11 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111, shift left << 2, 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100, and now I concatenate upper 4 bits of current PC which is 0010 and I finally get 0010 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1100 which is 0x2FFFFFFC, not 0x1FFFFFFC. Is this scenario possible in practice? If yes, then how to calculate the jump address correctly?

Comment: Can you format your question so it's easier to read?

Comment: That's right, but the "PC" value in question is the address of the instruction *after* the `j`.  (This would matter if you had a `j` at the very end of a 256 MiB region, so the top 4 bits change when incrementing after fetching the branch, before executing it.)

Comment: MIPS J-type instructions can only jump within the same 256 MiB region (except when the jump is the last word in the region); you'd need to use `b` (a relative jump) to reach `0x1FFFFFFC` from `0x20000000`

Comment: Can you jump between two addresses if their uppermost 4 bits are different?

Comment: Not with a `j` instruction, except in the special case of jump *from* `0x2FFFFFFC` to `0x3.......` since the absolute jump target is in the region containing the instruction after the `j`.  But like I said, yes, you can use a `b` instruction to jump between nearby addresses across a 256MiB boundary, or `lui`/`addiu` plus `jr` to jump anywhere.  (`b` is an alias for `beq $zero, $zero, target`, so it's an I-type relative branch.)

Comment: How can I check it in MIPS? I have tried to write la $t0 0x1FFFFFFC and jr $t0 but it seems wrong as I get errors.